# /bin/sh: 1: ./respondPalindromes: not found - What does this mean?

Tags: haskell, emacs, haskell-platform, haskell-mode

I am able to run the code below in terminal which is in respondPalindromes.hs file but failing to test the same in emacs.

> respondPalindromes = unlines . map (\xs -> if isPalindrome xs then "palindrome" else "not a palindrome") . lines
>      where isPalindrome xs = xs == reverse xs
>   main = interact respondPalindromes

Below is the terminal details:

> optimight@optimight:~$ cat words.txt | runhaskell respondPalindromes.hs
>   not a palindrome
>   palindrome
>   palindrome
>   palindrome

Below is the Emacs haskell-mode details:

> *Main> :load "/home/optimight/respondPalindromes.hs"
>   [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /home/optimight/respondPalindromes.hs, interpreted )
>   Ok, modules loaded: Main.
>   *Main> :! cat words.txt | ./respondPalindromes.hs
>   /bin/sh: 1: ./respondPalindromes.hs: Permission denied
>   *Main>  :! cat words.txt | ./respondPalindromes
>   /bin/sh: 1: ./respondPalindromes: not found
>   *Main>

Edit after Dietrich Epp's answer:

> *Main> !: cat words.txt | runhaskell respondPalindromes.hs
>   :12:1: parse error on input `!:'
>
> *Main> cat words.txt | runhaskell respondPalindromes.hs
>   :13:15: parse error on input `|'
>   *Main>

Comment: In your edit, you used `runhaskell`, but switched the `!` and the `:`. I believe it should be `:! cat words.txt | runhaskell respondPalindromes.hs`, not `!: cat words.txt | runhaskell respondPalindromes.hs`.

Comment: If you want to be able to run `./respondPalindromes.hs` without `runhaskell`,  add a shebang line; that is, add the line `#!/usr/bin/env runhaskell` as the very first line of the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the regular terminal window, you run this command:

```
cat words.txt | runhaskell respondPalindromes.hs
```

But in the Haskell window, you run the following shell command:

```
cat words.txt | ./respondPalindromes.hs
```

Why run a different command, if the first one works fine?

These are just ordinary shell commands.  If you haven't set up `respondPalindromes.hs` as an executable, then it won't run as an executable, you have to use `runhaskell` in order to execute it.

**Furthermore,** if you run the program this way (by executing a shell command from inside the Haskell interactive shell), there's no point to using a fancy Haskell shell.  You might as well be using an ordinary shell.

Instead, you may want to avoid the shell altogether, such as:

```
readFile "words.txt" >>= respondPalindromes >>= putStr
```

The `>>=` operator in Haskell is kind of like the `|` pipe in the shell.

**Summary:** The `:!` command executes an ordinary shell command, it doesn't have anything to do with Haskell.

Comment: I am an absolute haskell beginner and just going through the instructions given in LYAH for good and also trying to use emacs haskell-mode.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `haskell` but on command line you are executing `runhaskell respondPalindromes.hs` but inside `emacs` you are running `./respondPalindromes.hs`.

Pretty sure that is the problem.